# Timeout with multiple controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i try to understand the timeout in Angular, but i have a problem with using 
the timeout in the standard way together with with $scope.$apply. Why is the second controller
calling the first one ? The standard(first one) shouldn't work,but it is working after the second controller is called. Why?

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mydata1 = 'Timeout1...';
  setTimeout(function(){
      
        $scope.mydata1='1';   
      
      
    },2000);
  
});
app.controller('applyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mydata = 'Timeout2...';
  setTimeout(function(){
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.mydata='2';  
      });
      
    },6000);
  
});
app.controller('timeCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.mydata = 'Timeout3...';
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.mydata='3';
  },8000);
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Timeout</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.7"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <pre>1.Standard Timeout 2sec</pre>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mydata1">
    <h1>{{mydata1}}</h1>

  </div>
  <hr>
  <pre>2.With $scope.$apply 6sec</pre>
  <div ng-controller="applyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mydata">
    <h1>{{mydata}}</h1>

  </div>
  <hr>
  <pre>3.With $timeout 8sec</pre>
  <div ng-controller="timeCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mydata">
    <h1>{{mydata}}</h1>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular updates views when something changes is scope. Angular does not look whole time on scopes (because of performance), so it is rather like making message "hey, I have changed something, you can refresh views and run watchers." and `$apply` is this kind of thing.

When you are using something inside angular (like `$timeout`), angular knows, that you have probably changed something in scope and runs digest cycle, but when you are using `setTimeout`, angular does not notice that (beacause it happens outside).

The first one actually changes scope, but angular does notice that. The second one triggers view refresh after timeout callback execution and that is why view gets updated.

Obviously, you should not use first or second method. Third way is only valid way to do that.

You can check out more here: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Before you start reading, please have in mind, that using `{{ expression }}` in view calls `scope.$watch()` and creates watcher.